# Custom WP7 Popup control doesn't show content

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, popup

I'm trying to create a user control for a full screen pop-up that shows the EULA. I'm having trouble getting my content to show and I'm not sure why. I've created other pop-up controls and I don't see any layout differences between those and this one.

In Expression Blend, I can click on the LayoutRoot node and it shows my background style, but no content. If I click on the popEula node, I see the entire content, including the background style. When I add the control to a page, I only see the background. I'm not sure why all my content is disappearing.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Style="{StaticResource MyBackgroundStyle}">
    <Popup x:Name="popEula">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!--This section is empty. Place new content here Grid.Row="1"-->
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentGrid" Margin="24, 0, 24, 0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="435" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="LicenseText" Style="{StaticResource MyTextNormalStyle}"
                Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum bibendum semper ante a vestibulum. Ut ultricies tellus sit amet sapien viverra tempus. Sed auctor pretium purus, eu ornare libero malesuada a. Vivamus dignissim vulputate nunc, a venenatis sapien condimentum quis. Nam vestibulum, neque molestie rhoncus rutrum, ante lacus vulputate odio, ac tristique augue lacus ac mi. Donec a sollicitudin diam. Nulla facilisi. Ut eu purus felis, id faucibus urna. Nullam luctus porttitor cursus. Curabitur auctor leo vitae lorem fringilla at egestas mi sollicitudin. Vestibulum blandit tempor orci vel iaculis. Sed eleifend bibendum dapibus. Sed sed elit ac libero consequat interdum sit amet vitae lacus. Donec sit amet velit et nulla placerat iaculis. Nunc aliquam sollicitudin cursus. Sed sed tincidunt augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum bibendum semper ante a vestibulum. Ut ultricies tellus sit amet sapien viverra tempus. Sed auctor pretium purus, eu ornare libero malesuada a. Vivamus dignissim vulputate nunc, a venenatis sapien condimentum quis. Nam vestibulum, neque molestie rhoncus rutrum, ante lacus vulputate odio, ac tristique augue lacus ac mi. Donec a sollicitudin diam. Nulla facilisi. Ut eu purus felis, id faucibus urna. Nullam luctus porttitor cursus. Curabitur auctor leo vitae lorem fringilla at egestas mi sollicitudin. Vestibulum blandit tempor orci vel iaculis. Sed eleifend bibendum dapibus. Sed sed elit ac libero consequat interdum sit amet vitae lacus. Donec sit amet velit et nulla placerat iaculis. Nunc aliquam sollicitudin cursus. Sed sed tincidunt augue."/>
                </ScrollViewer>

                <toolkit:WrapPanel Grid.Row="2" Margin="0, 48, 0, 0">
                    <Button x:Name="btnAccept" Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" Content="Accept" Width="150"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnDecline" Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" Content="Decline" Width="150" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0" />
                </toolkit:WrapPanel>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by setting a width and heigh on your popup and also setting IsOpen = "true".  Looks like your popup isnt open or is a weird size and not showing properly.

Comment: Thank you. That was my problem. Can't believe I overlooked that.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson It looks like IsOpen = true doesnot show the popup instantly !!